# What is the best options for looping over NodeList?

Tags: html, dom

All looping variants work but which one is the right one to use for the NodeList and what differences are there I need to be aware of?

```
const els = document.querySelectorAll("div");

for (const el of Array.from(els)) {
 //..
};

Array.from(els).forEach((el) => {
 //..
});

Array.from(els).map((el) => {
 //..
});
```

Answer (score 1):

| For Loop | forEach Loop |
| --- | --- |
| It is one of the original ways of iterating over an array. | It is a newer way with lesser code to iterate over an array. |
| It is faster in performance. | It is slower than the traditional loop in performance. |
| The break statement can be used to come out from the loop. | The break statement cannot be used because of the callback function |
| The parameters are the iterator, counter, and incrementor. | The parameters are the iterator, index of item, and array to iterate. |
| It works with the await keyword. | The await keyword cannot be used due to the callback function. It may lead to incorrect output |

As always, the choice between map() and forEach() will depend on your use case. If you plan to change, alternate, or use the data, you should pick map(), because it returns a new array with the transformed data.